# How To Cancel The Change Event On A Select Control Using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a select control bound to a Knockout observable array:

```
<select data-bind="event: { change: selectedProductOfferingChange }, options: $parent.productTypes, optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: '-- Select --', value: selectedProductType, enable: !isReadOnly()"></select>
```

When the selection is changed, I want to run some code, perhaps make an AJAX call. If the change is not allowed, I want to cancel the change and display a modal dialog. I can't subscribe to the property as that will fire after the change has taken place. I would need the new value to determine if the change should be cancelled or not.

I tried the following in the viewmodel but the change is not cancelled though the property (selectedProductOffering) on the viewmodel is not updated:

```
self.selectedProductOfferingChange = function (data, event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
};
```

Could I use the "beforeChange" option with subscribe?

```
self.selectedProductType.subscribe(function (previous) {
}, self, "beforeChange");
```

Can the change be cancelled here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some thought, here's what I came up with:

```
self.selectedProductOfferingChange = function (data, e) {

    // Do any checking here
    if (confirm("OK to make this change ?")) { return; }

    // This stops the viewmodel property from being updated
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // Since the viewmodel property hasn't changed, force the view to update
    self.selectedProductType.valueHasMutated();
};
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't give you access to the new value. A computed will solve this issue:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.productTypes, optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: '-- Select --', value: computedSelectedProductType, enable: !isReadOnly()"></select>


   self.computedSelectedProductType = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.selectedProductType();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            // Do any checks here. If you want to revert to the previous
            // value, don't call the following but do call: 
            // self.selectedProductType.valueHasMutated()

            self.selectedProductType(value);
        },
        owner: self
    });
```

Comment: Nearly three years later, this solved my very issue -- with a minor tweak. I needed to add ko.computed(...).extend({notify: 'always'}) otherwise my dropdown would not revert back to the original value (Knockout v3.0.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, works like a charm! The explanation could be more clear though, in my opinion. I had to read it a couple times before I figured out what you meant.